# Is there a way to prevent inserting a duplicate object in SwiftData?

Tags: swift, swift-data

Coming in without a CoreData background, I was experimenting with SwiftData in an app and keep getting hit with the error:

> Duplicate registration attempt for object with id PersistentIdentifier(...)

Reading into the documentation, I saw the existence of the PersistenceModelID, but I don't understand how to use it. I tried to extrapolate from some old CoreData implementations on how to prevent objects with duplicate UUIDs and got the following which does not work:

```
let skinData = skinDataResponse.data // an array of objects

for skin in skinData {
    var fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Skin>()
    fetchDescriptor.predicate = #Predicate { item in
        skin.displayName == item.displayName
        // skin.id == item.PersistenModelID <- Tried these unsuccessfully as well
        // skin.id == item.id // UUID comparison
    }
    
    do {
        let existingSkin = try self.modelContext?.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
        
        if existingSkin?.first == nil {
            self.modelContext?.insert(skin)
        }
    } catch {
        print("SwiftData Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s not clear what you are trying to do, what is skinDataResponse.data and where does it come from?

Comment: For context, its an array of objects that I obtained by decoding a JSON from an API call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have labeled the `id` as `.unique` and leave `autosaveEnabled` with its default value of `true`; you don't need to worry about duplicates.

```
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID = UUID()
```

> The insert method works for both creating and updating model instances because the model indicates that the code parameter is unique.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/maintaining-a-local-copy-of-server-data

Comment: This + throwing self.modelContext?.insert(skin) into a  DispatchQueue.main.async {} block is what worked for me

Comment: According to https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-sync-swiftdata-with-icloud, `@Attribute(.unique)` cannot be used if you want iCloud sync to work (see also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/syncing-model-data-across-a-persons-devices). I'm getting the same error, btw, but need the iCloud sync, so this solution won't work for me.